# info window won't open at first click, instead it will show on second click event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using bellow code to open up a infowindow in my map

```
 //populate the  infowindow to defined marker map point
 function assignmarkerclick(marker1, index, message) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () {
         if (!infowindow) {
             infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
         }
         infowindow.setContent(message);
         infowindow.open(map, marker1);
     });
 }
```

// Shows the info window for the specified marker

```
function showMarker(index) {

    new google.maps.event.trigger(marker[index], 'click');
}
```

so when i click on the    "show point"  (assuming i am calling the showMarker()  javascript function "show point link" click event)    link  at first time info window wont open ,when i click on the  "show point "  link second time info window will open,
has any one had this bug before ?  could some one help me to sort this issue please ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your infowindow object as a global var, outside of the function:

```
// global var
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

 function assignmarkerclick(marker1, index, message) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function () {
         infowindow.setContent(message);
         infowindow.open(map, marker1);
     });
 }
```

Comment: but you have not *created* the object outside the function. When you do *new google.maps.InfoWindow()* the object is not ready for immediate use.

Comment: ah it was my mistake mate, its fixed now, thanks to your advice in here . your comments fixed my issue, u r a start ..

Comment: Hopefully a *star*, rather than a *start* ;-)